# VBA code for repeating on all cells until a blank cell is found

Tags: excel, vba

We receive spreadsheets with insurer information. Often Excel doesn't recognise the dates as dates, so it doesn't filter or pivot table.

If you f2 to go into the cell then it clicks it, and recognises it correctly.

As we get thousands of lines, we can't do this to each one. I recorded the macro of f2 enter which gave me:

```
Sub enter_f2()
    ' enter_f2 Macro
    ' Will open a cell and move to the next one
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("D7").Select
End Sub
```

I want to adapt this to run from wherever the highlighted cell is, in a loop until it hits a blank column and then stop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `Select` the set of cells you wish to process and run this:

```
Sub RefreshCells()
    Dim r As Range, rr As Range
    Set rr = Selection
    For Each r In rr
        r.Select
        If r.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
        Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
        Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
        DoEvents
    Next
End Sub
```

Run it while the worksheet is active, not from the VBE window.  Because it uses `Select / Edit` it will be a little slow.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly.  Everyone in the office is very appreciative now!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the code below for either DMY (xlDMYFormat) or MDY (xlMDYFormat) regional date format.

```
sub fixDates()
  with worksheets("sheet1")
    .range("d:d").TextToColumns Destination:=.range("D1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                                FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlMDYFormat)
  end with
end sub
```

For any single column selected,

```
sub fixDatesBtSel()
  with selection.columns(1)
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                   FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlMDYFormat)
  end with
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoUntilCellIsEmpty()

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
        Debug.Print ActiveCell.Value 'If cell is not empty print activecell value to immediate window 
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```